# Angular Service Throwing "Unknown Provider"

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm spinning my wheels on this. I'm trying to provide an instance of this service to my controller. When I run it, I get

> JavaScript runtime error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:
>   app.services.GithubServiceProvider <- app.services.GithubService <-
>   app.githubViewer.UserController

Here are the pieces:

1. Service itself

   ```
   module app.services {
   'use strict';

   export interface IGithubService {
       getUser(username: string): ng.IPromise<any>;
   }

   export class GithubService implements IGithubService {

       githubUrl: string = 'https://api.github.com/';

       static $inject = ['$http'];
       constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService) {

       }
       getUser(username: string): angular.IPromise<any> {
           return this.$http.get(this.githubUrl + "users/" + username)
               .then(response => response.data);
       }
   }

   angular
       .module('app.services')
       .service('app.services.GithubService', GithubService);
   ```

   }
2. The Controller

   ```
   module app.githubViewer {
   'use strict';

   interface IUserControllerScope { //scope definitions

   }

   class UserController implements IUserControllerScope {

       static $inject = ['app.services.GithubService', '$route'];
       constructor(githubService: app.services.IGithubService, $route: ng.route.IRouteService) {
      //...
       }

   }

   angular
       .module('app.githubViewer')
       .controller('app.githubViewer.UserController', UserController);
   ```

   }

Update, I looked at [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31094639/angular-js-unknown-provider-error) of common issues here, and it looks like it's all in order. Code is below:

Here is my main module declaration:

```
((): void => {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app', [
            'app.core',
            'app.services',
            /*
             *Feature Modules
             */
            'app.githubViewer'
        ]);
})();
```

And here is the service module declaration:

```
((): void => {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.services', []);
})();
```

I have triple checked to make sure the scripts are added to the page.

Please let me know if there is anything else I should post here. I'm a beginner on Angular and TypeScript.

Comment: Could you please provide your `app.githubViewer` module declaration ? Look at @emed answer and check if it's your problem.

Comment: emed was right. I'm not quite sure I understand why yet, but that fixed it. I was following a sample pretty rigidly that worked, and it did not have 'app.services' as a dependency for app.githubViewer because it was already a dependency of "app". I'll read some more about this.

Comment: Each module has it's own dependecies. The `app.` prefix is just to "organize" the modules in a hierarchy, but it's just a name, angular doesn't care about the module names. It doensn't matter if you put a dependency in you "main" module (`app`). If you need to use the dependency in another module you'll need to declare it as a dependency of that module too. If you have any doubts fell free to ask :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare `app.services` as a dependency for `app.githubViewer`

```
angular
    .module('app.githubViewer', ['app.services'])
```